# $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ is open with respect to any matrix norm on $\mathbb M_n(\mathbb C)$.

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $\mathbb M_n(\mathbb C)$ be the set of all $n\times n$ complex matrices. I am trying to show that $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ is open with respect to any matrix norm on $\mathbb M_n(\mathbb C)$.

I started by choosing a sequence $(A_k)_k$ in $\mathbb M_n(\mathbb C)$ such that $\det(A_k)=0$ for each $k$ such that $A_k\to A.$ Then it suffices to show that $\det(A)=0.$

Since 0 is an eigenvalue of $A_k$ for some $V_k\ne0$ we have $A_kV_k=0.$ I am trying to show that $V_k$ is convergent to some nonzero $V$ for then from the property of matrix norm it follows that $AV=0.$ But I cannot show that.

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the determinant to write $GL_n(\mathbb{C})=det^{-1}(\mathbb{C}^*)$, which shows that $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is open for the std. topology. Since on fininte dimensional vector spaces all norms are equivalent, they induce the same topology, so this show that $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is open for any norm.

Comment: I think due to the same logic of equivalence of norm we can say that $GL_n(\mathbb C)$  is dense. Can’t we?

Comment: But you still have to show that it is dense wr to some norm. I think this can be done in many ways. Just to give an idea think of a diagonalized matrix which is not invertible (ie it has some 0 eigenvalues). Then replace the zeroes by (small) $\epsilon$'s to get an invertible matrix which approximates the old one.